# How can i group Sentry events on Android?

Tags: android, sentry

I need to capture different messages to Sentry. For example, here i capture requests that took more time than allowed. But every capture creates a separate event record. It's producing a mess of events, that is hard to check.

```
private void checkResponseTime(Call call, Response response, double value) {
    long received = response.receivedResponseAtMillis();
    long sent = response.sentRequestAtMillis();
    float responseTime = (float) (received - sent) / 1000;
    if (responseTime > value) {
        String request = call.request().toString();
        Log.e("DEBUG", request + " response time is " + responseTime + " sec.");
        Sentry.capture(request);
    }
}
```

How to group them in Sentry under the same title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Sentry will try to use the location of the error (stack trace) and if that's not possible, the message, etc.

You can control the grouping through the Event property Fingerprint

https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-java/blob/master/sentry/src/main/java/io/sentry/event/Event.java#L295

Events with the same Fingerprint will be grouped together. So you can control it by setting the value yourself.

Comment: Thank you for this. I set transaction but still got ungrouped events: 

`Sentry.capture(new EventBuilder().withTransaction("Test").withMessage(request).build());`

Comment: Sorry, set Fingerprint to define the grouping. Not transaction. I updated the answer